# CodeIgniter - User Tracking

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have started a Facebook marketing campaign for website and web on Codeigniter, show advertise on Facebook, so when you click it will redirect to website directly.

Now I need to save data of users like, number of users coming from Facebook refer URL. 
For this reason I Google'd and found this [link](https://code.google.com/p/ci-usertracking/), but I don't know how to implement this in web. I even read the installation way, but I think I'm making some mistake.

Please guide me on how to implement this library in Codeigniter and get all details.

Comment: Why not use Google Analytics?  I think they've released some new abilities to track where stuff is coming from and such.  I've seen that information come across from Twitter and such?

Lastly the code on this is pretty old.  Just looking at it briefly I don't see anything that would keep it from working but I'd have to set it it up.  

Have you tried setting it up and seeing what errors you are getting?

Comment: you are right but in this framework lots of facilities and i am new of this framework so explore and learn codeigniter.